# Pod is not able to connect with local kafka running in my Kubernetes cluster at EKS

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, confluent-platform

I have deployed confluent kafka cluster using the helm chart with following command in voice namespace.

```
helm install local-kafka --set cp-schema-registry.enabled=false,cp-kafka-rest.enabled=false,cp-kafka-connect.enabled=false confluentinc/cp-helm-charts --namespace voice
```

As a result three zookeeper and three kafka brokers are up accessible at -

```
local-kafka-cp-kafka-headless:9092
or
local-kafka-cp-kafka.voice.svc.cluster.local:9092
```

Later I installed the other  microservices in the cluster who will be producing data on topic and some other microservice would be consuming.

But I am getting following error when a microservice tried to produce event -

```
"message":"producer::error writing msg: dial tcp: lookup local-kafka-cp-kafka.voice.svc.cluster.local on 20.0.0.2:53: no such host"
```

My services has some internal load balancer is also deployed. which is like -

```
internal-k8s-voice-myserver-85998808d7-3930233333.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

As per k8s documentation - the standard method to connect is

```
"{{ .Values.kafkasvc.name }}.{{ .Values.namespace }}.svc.cluster.local:9092
```

EDIT -
Here are the kafka service definition -

[image]

[image]

Here are the pod description which is trying to access the kafka broker on `local-kafka-cp-kafka.voice.svc.cluster.local:9092`

[image]

P.S. - both kafka and microservice which is trying to connect the kafka are in same namespace voice.

Please help Thanks.

Comment: Confluent Helm Charts are deprecated. Suggest you find an alternative. Also, load balancers do not work with Kafka clients

Comment: Please share your pod definition. Is it in the same namespace? Otherwise, you need a NetworkPolicy between different namespaces

Comment: @OneCricketeer Attached same in question. Thanks

Comment: Please use `local-kafka-cp-kafka:9092` if microservice and kafka in same namespace,
or not use `local-kafka-cp-kafka.voice:9092`.

Comment: @xirehat tried this with no luck, Just wanted to know since my microservice pod is deployed under Custom Resource(by my own operator) not as Kubernetes resource be reason for NO HOST?

Comment: @AshutoshPandey please deploy a test pod like nginx in voice namespace then exec to pod. install telnet then run `telnet local-kafka-cp-kafka 9092`. I think your cluster have dns issue

Comment: Like I said, find an alternative other than Confluent. Refer https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/17/accessing-kafka-part-1/